# What is the Wordpress Plugin or other way to replace thumnails of slider to the title of image

Tags: wordpress, slider

Replace thumnails to the title

[image]

I want to replace the thumbnails of the default slide, I use elementor for create but not found any topic talk about replace thumbnails to the title, could any expert tell me how to do this?

Comment: didnt get what is your question

Comment: my mean is how to create a slider that instead display the thumnails, I want to show the title of image, you can check my image I attachment above!